# Navigating back from Careers

Tags: discussion, jobs, navigation, top-bar

Will [Careers](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) be getting the new top bar?

If not, is there a reason there are no links to navigate back to any of the SE sites at the top? I suppose it's not a huge deal, but it's quite different from the rest of the SE sites.

The reason I ask is because now Careers is **prominently** displayed in the supercollider "sites" section.

Comment: Careers is not a Q&A site, unless I missed something...

Comment: I get that, but it's hard to deny the sites *are* related. I just assumed that you'd want people to be able to easily navigate there *and* back. Especially since the new top bar has a link directly to Careers in the SO/Meta section.

Comment: But only in the SO/Meta section - Careers is not currently as relevant to the rest of the network.

Comment: That sounds like a good reason for it to not get the top bar, but not such a good reason not to link back(at least to SO, which is what Careers is "tied" to).

Comment: Do you not see any footer links?

Comment: @random I do. Does anyone use footer links except as a last resort or overflow? Not sarcasm, I've just never thought to myself, "I wish this site used footer links for navigation."

Comment: Personally, yes. Footers before header links. A lot of sites use footer links to get around, the header saved for About and Contact and that's it

Comment: @Oded It was mentioned on the new Header Beta thread that the next version of the header will allow us to select which sites appear at the top of the dropdown for us. Will this include being able to remove the Careers and Meta subheadings (not that I want to remove meta, but if you can remove one it stands to reason you could remove the other)?

Comment: @WendiKidd - I don't know for sure, but it is likely - I am on other projects, so not entirely in the loop on all the details.

Comment: @WendiKidd - update on this. Apparently this is not planned. I don't have insight into the decision, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an update, the top bar (in a limited form) is now on [Stack Overflow Careers.](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/) More will be rolled out in the future, but this is a solid first step toward having a holistic experience across the Stack Exchange network. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Looks good! Check mark stolen :)

Answer (score 12):

Short Answer:  Yes, there will be further integration.

Longer Answer:  The new top bar roll out for SE is on the Careers team radar.  We're working on a few different integration type projects (which include better Company Page and Job Ads on Stack Overflow), and the navigation of Careers is on that list.  Currently, it's not the top priority, but we're aware of the pain point and will be addressing it.

This may not lead to an entirely redesigned top bar for Careers, but we'll be going over a few different options in the upcoming weeks.

Answer (score 2):

Oded's comment made clear that since Careers is not a Q&A site, it won't be getting the new top bar.

However I agree with you: listing Careers togheter with all the other Q&A sites in the new dropdown and not providing a uniform interface to navigate back once I clicked it is really bothersome from a UX point of view.

If you guys want people to use the dropdown to switch between sites, the interaction should be coherent for every site listed.

This doesn't necessarily mean that adding the new top bar is the way to go, but I think at least the dropdown should be there.

Comment: Part of the issue is one of implementation - the careers and the Q&A sites have vastly different codebases and implementing the new topbar would be extra work for both teams, for little gain.

Comment: @Oded I understand the implementation issue. However I think from a UX point of view is kind of unpleasant, so maybe a compromise could be reached. Instead of implementing the toolbar altogether, only the dropdown-switch could be added to Careers. Or at least a link to Stack Overflow in the same top-left position.

Comment: Not disagreeing with you. But I don't really know what the plans on the Careers side is. We certainly aim to integrate the two (Careers and SO) more.

Comment: @Oded that's good news. I think this question could easily be a feature request, to be marked as `status-review`